# VS Code locks mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

first time posting so please excuse any issues with my question.

I'm a web developer working in VS Code and as of yesterday it has started having a very strange issue. I start working and work for about 5 minutes before my mouse and keyboard both lock up. It seems to happen when I press ctrl but I press it while I'm working and nothing happens. It's only after a while.

They keyboard and mouse both stop and even disconnecting and reconnecting them doesn't help. I can plug them into new USB ports and they work just fine but I can't just keep changing ports every 5 minutes. The only fix is to restart my PC but it doesn't help for long.

One thing I did notice is that when I reconnect my mouse in a new port and I scroll in a Chrome window it zooms in and out as if the ctrl key is being held down.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You could try to uninstall and reinstall VS Code.

Comment: I was about to but I have changed the setup of my hubs to just experiment and it seems to be working. I will comment back after a little while to see if it's stable.